# Open selected menu in menubar by pressing enter

Tags: java, javafx

I want to enable the user to open menus in menubar with enter key press.

By default when you select menu in menubar in javafx, by example by pressing alt key, it opens when you press down arrow. I need it to open with enter key press. My program is meant to be accessible for visually impaired users and this is an expected standard.

I've already tried setting an event handler for the Menu object for KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED event. That didn't work, because it doesn't register any key presses.

Other than that I've tried setting onKeyPressed for the MenuBar, which didn't work either. Issue is the same, it doesn't register any key presses.

Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: Have you tried adding the key listener to the main scene/stage and then calling the menu.show() method?

Comment: I didn't, but I'll and I'll let you know :). Thanks!